# Nested while loop alternatives

Tags: c#, .net, loops, iteration

I have some code i wrote that follows this basic pattern below.  I am looking to see if there are better, more concise or better performing ideas to accomplish the same goal it is going for. the goal is to compare items in one list to items in another and perform an action if they match. the only way i have gotten it to work is the idea below, but i am new to c# and .net and am not sure if there are better ways.

```
list A
list B
int counter;
int counter2;
while (counter < comparison item)
{
    while (counter2 < comparison item 2)
    {
        if (A[counter] == B[counter2])
        {
            // do stuff
        }
        counter2++;
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: LINQ is a possibility, but it's functionally the same thing.

Comment: You can also sort the lists beforehand and do a merge join-type operation. Depending on the size of the lists and what kind of operations you plan on doing, it could be faster. As always, measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This two-loop construct is simple, but it is not performant. The problem is the number of comparisons: if the first set has `N` items and the second has `M`, then there would be `N*M` comparisons. With 1,000 items in each set, we're talking about 1,000,000 comparisons.

A better approach would be to hash the items of the first set, and then search the hash for the items from the second set. Since hashing is done in amortized constant time, you can do this in `M+N` operations, or about 2,000 for two sets of 1,000 items each:

```
var setA = new HashSet<int>(listA);
foreach (var b in listB) {
    if (setA.Contains(b)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

LINQ library lets you do this in even fewer lines of code:

```
foreach (var ab in listA.Intersect(listB)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, for the second example, would you use the lists as List objects or HashSet objects?

Comment: @wondergoat77 It does not matter what containers you pass into LINQ: it uses a hash-based container internally to make the merge, treating the input as `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you **don't need to change the lists** then you should use a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach (var itemA in A)
{
    foreach (var itemB in B)
    {
        if (itemA == itemB) {}
    }
}
```

If you **do need to change the lists** then you should use a `for` loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < A.Count; i++) 
{
    for (var j = 0; j < B.Count; j++)
    {
        if (A[i] == B[j]) {}
    }
}
```

If **the two lists are sorted** you can do this much more efficiently by going through the lists in order.

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

while (A.Length <= i && B.Length <= j)
{
    if (A[i] == B[j]) 
    {
        // items are equal
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    else if (A[i] > B[j]) // Comparison of the ordered value, could be a property on the item.
    {
        j++; // increment B's counter
    }
    else
    {
        i++; // increment A's counter
    }
}
```